# How to block all ip address and allow few ip address in particular country in htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ip

I can block the entire country IP address in the htaccess file. but in that, I want to allow a few IP addresses in that same country.  how to do it for a WordPress website. I tried with plugins also. none of the plugins are not having this options.

Comment: Are you ready to use plugin to block IP address.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you interested with blocking IP address using plugin, then use it.

> https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip-geo-block/

Comment: ya, I am using the same plugin to block IP in WordPress. thanks for ur reply.

Answer (score 0):

try deny the network segment, then allow the specific ip(my Router). it works for me;

```
deny from 180.110.125
allow from 180.110.125.xxx
```